# How can I read a password from the console, echoing splats?

Tags: c++, string

here i have written a code to accept a password entered by the user after he have entered his username,i have written a small code using do while statement to print out the star every time when ever user enter any character,& the loop terminates when the user enters a '!'.
but it surprised me when i see the password entered by the user,& the string length of the entered password,THE STRING length always comes out to be 21,in my case,& the output of password is a combination of the password entered by the user & the username......what's going on??????

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char username[15],password[15];
    int i=0;
    cout<<"\nEnter your USERNAME:";
    cin>>username;
    cout<<"\nenter your password:";

    do 
    {
        password[i]=getch();


        if(password[i]=='!')break;
        cout<<"*";
        i++;
    }while(i<15);
    cout<<"\n\nthe password entered was"<<password<<"\nthe length of the password is"           <<strlen(password);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using buffered streams on a cooked terminal is probably not a good way to read passwords. There used to be the `getpass()` function in `<unistd.h>`, but it's not threadsafe. Allegedly, the [Unix programmers FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq/) describes how to read without echo (section 3.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined:

```
char password[15];
```

And as per your loop, it continues until `i` is equal to `14` (i.e, *15th character*). So there is no space for *NULL termination*. Let it be like this:

```
char password[16];
```

Now, just after the loop, add:

```
password[i] = 0;
```

`i` will be at `15` if user didn't enter '!' and if he did, it will be replaced with `NULL` character. I think this is the easiest fix. If you don't want the '!' to be replaced, place `i++;` before `break;`

Comment: ok that's cool,but why the string length always comes out to be 21,why the username is catenated when i print out string of the password...??

Comment: I agree with @Blaze, without having NULL at the end, the next memory address maybe allocated to the username and hence the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You are not terminating your string with a NULL.

```
do 
{
    password[i]=getch();
    if(password[i]=='!') break;
    cout<<"*";-
    i++;
}while(i<15);
if (i < 15) password[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: The termination should be unconditionally. It would be better to have the string one element longer than the input.

Comment: ok that's cool,but why the string length always comes out to be 21,why the username is catenated when i print out  string of the password...??

Comment: strlen is scanning past index 15 and finds a null at 21.

Comment: The password is just a memory address.  strlen simply scans memory until a NULL is encountered.  When you failed to set NULL on password, the rest of the characters are random garbage (i.e non NULL).

Answer (score 1):

A C string must be terminated by the special character `'\0'`, which is not the case with your password/username. You have to set the `i+1`th character to `'\0'`:

```
password[i]=getch();
password[i+1] = '\0';
```

Also you have to consider that your password buffer must also contain this string, so you have just space for 14 characters if you define `char password[15];` so your loop can just go to 14.

Answer (score 1):

You read 15 characters but you never write a '\0' in the string so it's not terminated.

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

please correct that. If your compiler does not know these files, then your compiler is not any good.

Then, why don't you use std::string instead if char-arrays?
That would avoid any of these errors.
What you do here, is a mix of c and c++.

Comment: but the operations i have performed are completely valid for c++ too,i would appreciate if you tell me about the reason behind the above behaviour of string......

Comment: You won't be bothered with an error like this - like forgetting the \0 termination. Also, string is a class and has many convinient functions. You can also access a single character with the [] operator. You have access to the length with length() and to the size(), you can resize() it if needed to preallocate and so on. There are many reasons. #include <string.h> makes your code incompatible to newer compilers. .h is deprecated for compiler-includes in c++. And now I am out of space here xP.

Comment: YO...but i found it more than enough...:p..thanx..:)

Comment: Read also here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/39622/ and here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4878/